# Updating MS Project (.mpp file) SubProject from its the master project inside a Document library, will raise an error that the SubProject is Read-Only

Tags: 2013, document-library, administration, office, ms-project

We have a document library inside a SharePoint enterprise server 2013 Team site. and inside this document library we have uploaded some Project plans. where we have master project plans and sub-project plans uploaded inside the document library. now we are facing these issues when we try to update a sub-project from the Master project , where when we try to save the sub-project it will say that the sub-project is Read-only, Here is the full scenario:-

1- we can update a sub-project directly from the project plan, and the changes will automatically update in the master project. which is fine.

2- But when we try to update the sub-project within the master project, the sub-project does not update and when we try to save the changes we will get a message that the sub-project file is "Read only".

so can anyone adivce how we can fix this ? so we will be able to update sub-projects from the master project plan ?

Comment: John...are both items being checked out?

Comment: @jpollar Now the master project is inside one docuemnt library (under subsiteA),, while the sub-project is on another document library (under subsiteB) but both subsiteA & subsiteB are inside the same site collection.. so now when i click on the master project under subsiteA and edit it,, what i need to do to the sub-project under subsiteB ? do i need to edit it also ?

Comment: From what I'm understanding, you want to be able to edit either or both when needed. The first thing that comes to mind is that you need to make sure that both are checked out, so you don't get read-only errors.

Comment: @jpollar Now we have 2 MS project files (.mpp files). and each project file is uploaded inside different document library. now in MS project you can link 2 projects together... so now editing each project by itself is working well. but if we link the master project with the subproject, we can edit the master project,, but if from inside the master project, i try to edit the subproject i will get an error that the subproject is read only... but if i directly edit the sub-project then it will work fine

Comment: @jpollar here is a sample of how to create a master project  and subproject https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Link-projects-to-create-a-master-project-36bcd34d-db5c-403a-9eca-90e878920f2a?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Comment: can you upload screenshots of the error?